# how to create rtl tab slider with Jssor Slider Plugin

Tags: jquery, tabs, slider, right-to-left, jssor

I used the Jssor slider, But my problem with it for rtl tab direction on usage tab slide.
I want to arrange tabs right to left and slide show begin from right to left.

See the orginal demo:

http://www.jssor.com/demos/tab-slider.html

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set $StartIndex to 4 (the last index of your slides), and set $AutoPlaySteps to -1.

```
var options = {
    ...
    $StartIndex: 4,  //if you have 5 slides, the last index is 4 then
    $AutoPlaySteps: -1,
    ...
};
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer this is correct but not a perfect way to fix this problem.
The slider tabs are reverse and float:right in css do not work for fix this problem.
I do not like to use reverse array from end to first to create my slider.